# Discord Bot Read single lines and then deleting them

Tags: javascript, discord.js, fs

I am building a bot that stores values in a .txt file one code in each line. 
Now I want to grab only one line of the txt file and then delete the line.

It doesnt work the way I do it tho bc I have no idea how to delete a single line and then write a new file

```
bot.on("message", message=>{

    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");



    switch(args[0]){

         case "code": 
         let codetext = message.content.replace(prefix + "code", "")

        fs.appendFile("./text.txt", codetext + "\n",(err)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
                  message.channel.send("message written")
          })
        break;
        case "getcode":

        let getcode = fs.readFileSync("./text.txt", "utf8", (err)=>{
            if (err) throw err;
        })
        var code_array = getcode.split("\n")
        message.channel.send(code_array[0])

        }    
    });
```

Comment: I would like to strongly, *strongly* advocate against ever using a custom plaintext storage format like this in JavaScript. You have access to JSON functions in every js file and every scope, use them!

Comment: any recommendation how i can solve my problem tho ?

Comment: I am going to mirror what Klaycon said.  Ideally you would your data as arrays in JSON.  Then you can just grab the array and pop or splice, etc. to delete elements and then stringify and overwrite the old file.  Nevertheless, you can do that with what you have here, you create code_array, so you need to pop or shift or splice out the ones you want gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already made an array so you just need to remove the elements you want out and rewrite what's left back to the file, overwriting the old.  There are a few ways to do this, all of the following will alter the original array:

Remove the last element and return what was removed.

```
let popped = code_array.pop()
```

Remove the first element and return what was removed.

```
let shifted = code_array.shift()
```

Remove 3 items starting at the element index 2 (the 3rd element, it's 0 based!) and return an array of what was removed.

```
let spliced = code_array.splice(2, 3);
```